# Why can't function in JavaScript "Class" call itself?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. Firefox's error console tells me: "*this.animateImgSlider is not a function*".

What I would like is to call `this.selectImage()` with `jsItems[0].selectImage(0)` and then have `this.animateImgSlider()` be called some number of times until `selfCall` is false:

```
function WindowItem(inId) {
    this.id = inId;
    this.imgSliderTarget = 0;
    this.imgSlider = document.getElementById("imgSlider"+inId);

    this.animateImgSlider = function() {
        var selfCall = true;
        var currLeft = parseInt(this.imgSlider.style.left, 10);
        if (currLeft < this.imgSliderTarget) {
            currLeft += 8;
            if (currLeft >= this.imgSliderTarget) {
                currLeft = this.imgSliderTarget;
                selfCall = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            currLeft -= 8;
            if (currLeft <= this.imgSliderTarget) {
                currLeft = this.imgSliderTarget;
                selfCall = false;
            }
        }
        this.imgSlider.style.left = currLeft+"px";
        if (selfCall) setTimeout("this.animateImgSlider()", 0);
    }

    this.selectImage = function(inImg) {
        this.imgSliderTarget = -inImg*488;
        this.animateImgSlider();
    }
}
var jsItems = new Array();
jsItems.push(new WindowItem(0));
```

This line is the one that throws the error:

```
if (selfCall) setTimeout("this.animateImgSlider()", 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
if (selfCall) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.animateImgSlider();
    }, 0);
}
```

(of course, it would make more sense to me to declare `self` at the top and use that throughout the function instead of `this`)

A string that is passed to `setTimeout` to execute is done so in the global scope, meaning `this` refers to `window`. It is not executed in the current scope, where the `setTimeout` call is.

On a side note, as a suggestion, I would move your `animateImgSlider` and `selectImage` methods outside, and into the `WindowItem` prototype, so that they can be shared by all instances, instead of creating a new anonymous function each time. So for example, you'd have:

```
function WindowItem(inId) {
    // blah blah
}

WindowItem.prototype.animateImgSlider = function () {
    // blah blah
};

WindowItem.prototype.selectImage = function(inImg) {
    // blah blah
};
```

The value of `this` will still refer to the specific instance, unless of course you attempt to use it in a string for the `setTimeout` parameter :)

This is clearly not required, as your code currently works fine, but it is a commonly used convention for declaring methods on a constructor function for instances to share.

Comment: @asimes No problem, glad it worked! I just updated my answer with some extra random things you might want to look at.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the advantage of using prototype, what is being created each time in my code?

Comment: Prototype is a must if your object will be created many times, instead of recreating the object everytime in full, your object will inherit its prototype that are shared across all instances.

Comment: @asimes The methods created with `prototype` are done once and reference one place. With your code, every time you call `new WindowItem()`, the function is called, meaning it creates a new object and sets properties (and methods) by using `this.X = Y` for that specific new object. So every time that happens, it creates a new anonymous function and assigns it to `animateImgSlider` and another to `selectImage`. With `prototype`, it creates a property/method inherited by all objects constructed with `new WindowItem()`, and references a single anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bind .here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
if (selfCall) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.animateImgSlider();
    }.bind(this), 0);
}
```